# Object's **hashCode** function - how does jdk uses it?

Tags: java, hashtable

I know that whenever you override `equals` method you should also override `hashCode` method .

But what Im not sure is, how does **JDK** uses it?

For example `HashSet`/`HashMap` are set/map implementation using hash table, So is correct to say that this table use the object's hash_code as key for their hash_function?

Comment: Yes, an objects `hashCode` method is used as the hash function in the `HashSet` and `HashMap` classes.

Answer (score 1):

> So is correct to say that this table use the object's hash_code as key for their hash_function?

Almost. `hashCode()` is actually the hash function. So `HashMap` whenever it tries to find the key or put the key, it calls the key `hashCode()` method and uses it (with some bit mask)to find proper element in the hash table.

Also note it's not used directly by JVM but justby some classes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is readily found in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

> If many mappings are to be stored in a HashMap instance, creating it with a sufficiently large capacity will allow the mappings to be stored more efficiently than letting it perform automatic rehashing as needed to grow the table. Note that using many keys with the same `hashCode()` is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties.

So yes, `HashMap` uses `hashCode`.

You can also see [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f), as the JDK is open source. (You'll find it in `src.jar` in your JDK installation.)